# Getting a descending range sequence in Ruby

Tags: ruby, range

So this works ascendingly

```
(1..5).to_a => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But this doesn't

```
(5..1).to_a => []
```

I'm trying to get a descending sequence from an arbitrary ceiling. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
5.downto(1).to_a # => [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Of course, there's a corresponding `#upto`. If you want steps, you can do this:

```
1.step(10, 2).to_a # => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
10.step(1, -2).to_a # => [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 7):

Or you can try this:
`(1..5).to_a.reverse # => [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

Comment: Note that for this particular question, which already materializes the array from the range with `to_a`, this is fine, but in contrast to the `#downto` suggestion above, this requires the array to be materialized (linear memory), while something like `5.downto(1)` gives a descending enumerator (constant memory).